# jQuery dynamic slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-slider

Any idea why this won't work? What I'm trying to do is add some div tags dynamically and then apply them with a slider.

```
    $(function () {

        var testarea =  $('<div id="testarea" />');

        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            $('<div class="testslider"></div>').appendTo(testarea);
        }

        $('#somearea').html(testarea.html());

        $(".testslider").slider({
            value: 100,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            step: 100,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
            }
        });
   });
```

html:

```
<div id="somearea"></div>
```

If I just add the div tags normally like so then its ok so I'm not too sure how to apply it dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May as well just do it in one go anyway

```
$(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        $('<div class="testslider"/>').slider({
            value: 100,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            step: 100,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
            }
        }).appendTo('#testarea');
    }
});
```

Comment: what if the <div id="testarea"></div> was also dynamic and not hard coded?

Comment: Won't make a difference. Try it.

Comment: Basically it'll just print out [object object]

Comment: What will print out [object object] and where?

Comment: I was trying to do something like this var sliderarea = $('<div id="testarea" />'); then $('<div class="slidertest" />').slider({ ..... ).appendTo(sliderarea); now I want to display this sliderarea. If I use sliderarea its [object Object], so I tried sliderarea.html() but the content isn't being shown.

Comment: Try `.appendTo(sliderarea); ` not `append(sliderarea); `